# esc_url( ) won't use https

Tags: php, functions

The code on the page looks like this:

```
if ( ! empty( $image ) ) : ?>
<div class="headshot">
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" alt="Photo of <?php echo esc_attr( $author_name ); ?>"/>
</div>
```

But when the image shows up on the page it's using http instead of https like the rest of the site.

When go to the [WP codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) to see the usage for esc_url it shows me this under usage but I don't know the correct syntax to use to make the protocol forced to https:

```
<?php esc_url( $url, $protocols, $_context ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

esc_url never force the URL to protocol it's only checking and escaping the passed URL from invalid characters, the $protocols variable is an array of acceptable (white list) protocols not for forcing destination URL.

```
// Forcing URL to https instead of http

$YOUR_URL = esc_url($YOUR_URL);

if( 'http' == parse_url($YOUR_URL, PHP_URL_SCHEME) ){
    $NEW_URL = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $YOUR_URL); 
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to force it to use https?

Comment: if your website under https enable Administration Over SSL [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL) otherwise you can force it manually like this 

if(parse_url($YOUR_URL, PHP_URL_SCHEME) == 'http'){
$NEW_URL = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $YOUR_URL);
}

Answer (score 0):

The `$protocols` parameter accepts an array, so:

```
$protocols = array(
  'https'
);
```

But "https" is listed as a default so I am not sure that is the problem. My guess is that there is a filter interfering... `clean_url` for example, or `kses_allowed_protocols`

Comment: I need it to force https so it won't do http. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but i had similar issue today. If you install SSL Insecure Content Fixer plugin, then go on setting once installed and select 'Capture All' and save.

This fixed the issue for me. Make sure you back up your database and site beforehand just incase something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The function you were looking for (but didn't land until dec 2015), is [set_url_scheme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_url_scheme/)

`set_url_scheme( $url, 'https' ) )`

Internally the function checks if is_ssl is true, will only set the url scheme if the passed url has a scheme.